# passing arguments to drivers probe function

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

In the call chain of module_i2c_driver() i am not able to find that where arguments are passed to the function adxl34x_i2c_probe().

```
    static int adxl34x_i2c_probe(struct i2c_client *client,
 78                                        const struct i2c_device_id *id)
 79 {
            ...
 99         return 0;
100 }

158 static struct i2c_driver adxl34x_driver = {
159         .driver = {
160                 .name = "adxl34x",
161                 .owner = THIS_MODULE,
162                 .pm = &adxl34x_i2c_pm,
163                 .of_match_table = of_match_ptr(adxl34x_of_id),
164         },
165         .probe    = adxl34x_i2c_probe,
166         .remove   = adxl34x_i2c_remove,
167         .id_table = adxl34x_id,
168 };
169 
170 module_i2c_driver(adxl34x_driver);
```

Comment: you should look for the documentation...

Comment: You don't need to care. Why are you asking this?

Comment: @AK_ : i think they dont have any for that.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko : I just want to know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i2c_driver`'s `probe` callback is called from `i2c_device_probe` function (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L632).

With

```
.probe    = adxl34x_i2c_probe
```

you're setting callback function pointer of `probe` to point to `adx134x_i2c_probe`, so calling `driver->probe` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c#L672) with passed arguments is actually calling `adxl34x_i2c_probe` with the same arguments.